# Enum to Type maping

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I have enum which looks as :

```
public enum FieldType
{

    Text,
    Image,
    ProgressBar,
    Group,
}
```

I want to write a method which will return the type of class which user has to instantiate for field type in c#.

I want to delegate the task of creating object to the user of my Api. I know which all type each enum maps to. It just that I can't return some common or base type as it will won't tell user which type of object they have to create.

for instance, user needs to add text field. so I want to return the type TextBox which have to be instantiated and pass on the required properties

If I take base class or interface, it won't help. As I need to expose the type not the object.

if I use 'Type' Class, then they have to use reflection and still won't get know which properties they have to pass on

I don't know if it is right way to solve it Or should I consider different approach. I am open for both solution.

The reason why I find it better to expose type to the user because user will get to know what properties being expected in instantiation.

Alternatively, I could write base property interface and user will pass the property name and value and I would set the property of that object using reflection.

```
interface IProperty<T>
{
  string propertyName {get;set;}

  T Value {get;set;}
}
```

but how I would educate user that which properties are being expected.

Comment: Do you know the types of classes?

Comment: Did you tried something, what is the specific problem you stuck with?

Comment: A `Dictionary<FieldType, Type>`? E.g. `private static Dictionary<FieldType, Type> s_ControlTypes = new Dictionary<FieldType, Type>() {{FieldType.Text, typeof(TextBox)}, {FieldType.Image, typeof(ImageBox)}};`

Comment: but this will return type T , How they would get to know which type it is. Either I will use it Activator.CreateInstance() and give type. But What I want it should TextBox instead of Type. So Idea of having base type or interface won't help

Comment: Since it is an Enum, I would probably just make a Builder that takes the enum as a parameter.

you can not really return the actual type, but since they are all abstracted from Control, you could just return that.

Comment: I want to delegate the task of creation to the user. if i had to create the type, i would have done it using builder or reflection anything.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very simple way of doing it, but as you only use an Enum, I would just keep it simple, you can then later in your code check what type of instance you have if you need to do specific stuff on them.

```
class MyControlBuilder
{
    public Control Build(FieldType fieldType)
    {
        switch (fieldType)
        {
            case FieldType.Text:
                return new TextBox();
            case FieldType.Image:
                return new PictureBox();
            case FieldType.ProgressBar:
                return new ProgressBar();
            case FieldType.Group:
                return new GroupBox();
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

an example of how to use it:

```
        var builder = new MyControlBuilder();
        var control = builder.Build(FieldType.ProgressBar);
        if(control is ProgressBar progressBar)
        {
            progressBar.Minimum = 0;
            progressBar.Maximum = 100;
            progressBar.Value = 0;
        }
```

Comment: I don't need to return object. I need to return Type. I want to leave the task of creating object to the caller. So, in the constructor, they will get to know which properties they need to pass on.

Comment: then you just change the return type to T, and return typeof() the control you want the type of. just the same.

Comment: type of return 'Type'.

Comment: return typeof(ProgressBar);

Comment: that will return Type T = typeof(ProgressBar). Now tell me how user create object.Activator.CreateInstance(T). this is not what I want. I want it return TextBox and user type TextBox box = new TextBox(text, bindiing, any properties);

Comment: as I mentioned in my answer, I would just use the new ProgressBar, instead of using reflections, as it can go very wrong. that way you can easily get the Type of the initialized object since there is no reason for a user to manipulate your constructor.

Comment: controls are made to be changed, and just edit them before you attach them to your form.

Answer (score 0):

When asked about *mapping*, `Dictionary<K, V>` is the first that comes to mind, e.g.

```
 private static Dictionary<FieldType, Type> s_ControlTypes = 
   new Dictionary<FieldType, Type>() {
     {FieldType.Text, typeof(TextBox)}, 
     {FieldType.Image, typeof(ImageBox)},
 };

 ...

 Control ctrl = Activator.CreateInstance(s_ControlTypes[FieldType.Text]) as Control;
 ...
```

Or (let's put the entire procedure of control creating into the dictionary):

```
 private static Dictionary<FieldType, Action<Control>> s_ControlCreators = 
   new Dictionary<FieldType, Action<Control>() {
     {FieldType.Text, () => {
        // You can well have an elaborated procedure  
        var result = new TextBox();

        result.Readonly := true;

        return result; 
      }}, 
     {FieldType.Image, () => new ImageBox()},
 };

 ...

 Control ctrl = s_ControlCreators[FieldType.Text]();
 ...
```

Finally, you can impelemnt an *extension method* for the initial `enum`:

```
 public static class FieldTypeExtensions {
   public static Control CreateControl(this FieldType value) {
     return s_ControlCreators[value]();  
   }
 }
```

and have

```
 FieldType fieldType = FieldType.Text;

 ...

 Control ctrl = fieldType.CreateControl();
```